# Copy values from a hash to a data frame in R using the hash package

Tags: r, hash, dataframe

I'm trying to copy the values of a hash to a data frame in r.
I am using the hash package in r to construct my hash:
[Link to hash package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/hash/index.html)

I have been able to insert the date into a hash fine using the following code:

```
hash_test <- read.delim("hash_test.txt")
sizeH = nrow(hash_test)
h = hash()

for(i in 1:sizeH){

    w = hash_test[i,4]
    x = hash_test[i,5]
    value = hash_test[i,]
    hkey = paste(w, x, sep = "")
    .set( h, keys=hkey, values=value )
}
```

I am trying to copy the keys into a data frame using the following:

```
h_vals = keys(h)
size = length(h_vals)
h_new = rep(0,size)

for(i in 1:size){
    current_key = h_vals[i]
    h_new[i] = h[[current_key]]
}
```

This is not copying all of the values for a given key however.  If I try to access indevidual keys it works fine:

```
h[["Ube2d2GCAC"]]

LN.Tfr.1 LN.Tfr.2 LN.Tfr.3 Gene   UMI
40.693   12.884   22.59467 Ube2d2 GCAC
```

Here is some sample data I used to test.  The actual data is much larger:

```
LN.Tfr.1    LN.Tfr.2    LN.Tfr.3    Gene    UMI
27.129      25.324      19.49333333 Tubgcp6 GCCC
8.887       8.886       5.924333333 Tubgcp6 GCCC
4.21        14.661      9.017       Uba52   GTTT
40.693      12.884      22.59466667 Ube2d2  GCAC
1.871       2.221       1.364       Ube2d3  GCAG
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use "as.character" function in your code.
when you use as.character, hash table "h" can recognize some character instead of number.

```
h_vals = keys(h)
size = length(h_vals)
h_new = rep(0,size)

for(i in 1:size){
    current_key = h_vals[i]
    current_key = as.character(current_key)
    value_h = as.list(h[current_key])
    h_new[i] = value_h
}
```

Good luck

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution to this problem as well:

```
h = hash()
for( i in 1:nrow(hash_test) ) {
    w = hash_test[i,4]
    x = hash_test[i,5]
    z = paste(w, x, sep = "")
    h[z] = i
}
```

Provided by: Christopher Brown